# How to view certain cell's value (not formula), while data_only=False? openpyxl, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Using the following code, how can I take a value (not the formula) from an excel file's cell to another excel file's cell while maintaining  `data_only = False`?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
#load excel file
counter = 0
workbook_process = load_workbook(filename="file.xlsx", data_only = False)
sheets_process = workbook_process.sheetnames
sheets_process_parameters = workbook_process[sheets_process[1]]
sheets_process_output = workbook_process[sheets_process[7]]

workbook_data_streaming = load_workbook(filename="file2.xlsx", data_only = True)
sheets_workbook_data_streaming = workbook_data_streaming.sheetnames
sheet_data_streaming = workbook_data_streaming[sheets_workbook_data_streaming[1]]



sheet_data_streaming.cell(row=5, column=34).value = sheets_process_output["G57"].value

workbook_data_streaming.save(filename="Process1.xlsx")
```

The problem is that the following line

```
sheet_data_streaming.cell(row=5, column=34).value = sheets_process_output["G57"].value
```

is assigning a formula to `sheet_data_streaming.cell(row=5, column=34).value`, not the value calculated in `sheets_process_output.`

Comment: `data_only=False` will give you the fomulae. This needs to be `True` to get the values.

Comment: The problem is that I need to perform a calculation in the main file and send the result to another excel file @CharlieClark